# How to assign a string variable value to a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to populate a 2d array with String values.

int m; n; are used in my loops to assign to rows and columns.

In an inner loop I am pulling out strings from a separate string array and assigning each value to a string variable. Then I am trying to assign that string variable to the 2d array of strings.

String variable = value of string in string array at a specific index;

```
String[m][n] example =  variable;
```

It seems to working fine except it doesn't seem to be loading the string in the string variable into the 2d array.

Can anyone help me to understand why this is happening and how I might successfully assign the data to the 2d array?

```
for(m = 0; m < people.size(); m++){
        for(n = 0; n < people.get(m).getNames().length; n++){

            for(int i = 0; i < people.size(); i ++){
                for(j = 0; j < people.get(i).getNames().length; j++){
                    String name = people.get(i).getNames()[j];

                }
        NamesGrid [m][n] =  name;

        }
```

Comment: For the inner loop, are you sure about your curlybracket? There 2 for loop but you only close 1 yet the indent is not at the place where it should be if you only close one. Also why are you always assigning al these value to the same String before you even assign to your 2d array?

Comment: Why _four_ nested loops?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell just what you want to accomplish.  The fact that you've posted non-matching curly braces doesn't help.

But basically, a double to populate all the array elements would look like:

```
for(m = 0; m < people.size(); m++){
    for(n = 0; n < people.get(m).getNames().length; n++){
        namesGrid[m][n] = ?????????;
    }
}
```

where you have to fill in the expression.  (And maybe add some code above the assignment to help with the computation.)

So what info do we have at the point where the array element is being assigned?  We know what `m` and `n` are--the row and column of the `namesGrid` array.  It also looks like they are also the "row" and "column" of objects in some `people` object.  (It looks like `people` has several lists of names, and `people.get(i)` gives you one list of names?  I'm not sure.)

But since we already know the row and column numbers for `people`, i.e. `m` and `n`, we can use those to access the data in `people`.  We don't need extra `for` loops to do that.  Or, to look at it another way: you need to iterate through all the elements of `namesGrid`, and you need to iterate through all the `people`, *but you are iterating over them at the same time* since the two structures are roughly the same shape, so to speak.  When you use `m` and `n` to iterate through `namesGrid`, they are also iterating through `people`.  So you don't need extra loops to iterate through `people`.

So get rid of those two extra `i` and `j` loops, and just use `m` and `n` to get the name:

```
String name = people.get(m).getNames()[n];
```

If this isn't what you really wanted, please edit your question and provide more details.  Also, variable names by convention begin with a lower-case letter in Java, so I've changed `namesGrid` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try going through the 2d array using two for loops. Here is some sample code that goes through a for loop and assigns every element with a string. 
    String[][] names = new String[14][10];

```
    for(int rows = 0; rows < names.length; rows++) {
        for(int cols = 0; cols < names[0].length; cols++) {
            names[rows][cols] = "Strings!";
        }
    }

    for(int rows = 0; rows < names.length; rows++) {
        for(int cols = 0; cols < names[0].length; cols++) {
            System.out.print(names[rows][cols]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```